# Identify HTML block elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have simple one column HTML files ([ebooks](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/17953/17953-h/17953-h.htm) from Gutenberg Project).

I want to identify in the DOM the **block** elements (like `<h1> <p> <div> <table> etc`, not `<a> <em> <b> etc`) and enclose them in `<div>` tags.

Is there any easy way to do it in jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a selector for the elements elements you want and call [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) for each, like this:

```
$("h1, p, div, table").wrap("<div></div>");
```

This would wrap *each* one in a `<div>` individually.  It looks from your example page they use a known set of elements, so just add whichever one you want to the selector.

Comment: Great, and here is a list of HTML block-level elements: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html - thanks Nick